# Why FileAppender is not locking the file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback, spring-logback

Have a problem with logback.Have a logback.xml file find it below.
Each thread has a single log file. However, cant recognize file is done or thread is done with looking the file. File is not locked or something. I dont wanna write a code to get content of file which I mean, dont wanna write a some symbol to find out file is done. I have been searching it for 3 months :)
I hope you help me.
Many thanks.

```
 <appender name="SIFT" class="XXXXX.SiftingAppender">
    <discriminator>
        <key>fileLocation</key>
        <defaultValue>${user.home}\start.log</defaultValue>
    </discriminator>
    <sift>
        <appender name="FILE-${fileLocation}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
            <file>${fileLocation}</file>
            <append>false</append>
            <encoder>
                <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
        </appender>
    </sift>
</appender>
```

Comment: no one has commented yet :(